`useContentManagerInitData` must be used within `StrapiApp` error in Strapi project
This will be the first time I am getting this error message in strapi.
I deployed my strapi project on shared host cpanel, I want able to deploy it to work.
When I registered and logged in I got no error on the home page, but when I clicked on content manager, Media Library and Content-Type builder I got the following error.
For Content Manager
Content Manager Error
Error: `useContentManagerInitData` must be used within `StrapiApp`
    at https://strapi.demia.org/admin/strapi-HBU9X4md.js:2448:6808
    at Kle (https://strapi.demia.org/admin/strapi-HBU9X4md.js:2293:4907)
    at i (https://strapi.demia.org/admin/strapi-HBU9X4md.js:2448:6775)
    at Fe (https://strapi.demia.org/admin/layout-CrTxOnCy-DGaBQwRX.js:28:1605)
    at Ye (https://strapi.demia.org/admin/layout-CrTxOnCy-DGaBQwRX.js:28:3638)
    at f$ (https://strapi.demia.org/admin/strapi-HBU9X4md.js:40:17031)
    at QX (https://strapi.demia.org/admin/strapi-HBU9X4md.js:42:44091)
    at WX (https://strapi.demia.org/admin/strapi-HBU9X4md.js:42:39809)
    at ITe (https://strapi.demia.org/admin/strapi-HBU9X4md.js:42:39735)
    at HS (https://strapi.demia.org/admin/strapi-HBU9X4md.js:42:39585)

For Media Library
Media Library Error
Error: `useRBAC` must be used within `Auth`
    at https://strapi.demia.org/admin/strapi-HBU9X4md.js:2448:6808
    at Kle (https://strapi.demia.org/admin/strapi-HBU9X4md.js:2293:4907)
    at i (https://strapi.demia.org/admin/strapi-HBU9X4md.js:2448:6775)
    at wl (https://strapi.demia.org/admin/strapi-HBU9X4md.js:2463:2412)
    at dhe (https://strapi.demia.org/admin/strapi-HBU9X4md.js:2575:64396)
    at Xs (https://strapi.demia.org/admin/index-fPsIi9fE-Dirr-e3P.js:14:119)
    at f$ (https://strapi.demia.org/admin/strapi-HBU9X4md.js:40:17031)
    at QX (https://strapi.demia.org/admin/strapi-HBU9X4md.js:42:44091)
    at WX (https://strapi.demia.org/admin/strapi-HBU9X4md.js:42:39809)
    at ITe (https://strapi.demia.org/admin/strapi-HBU9X4md.js:42:39735)

For Content-Type Builder
Content-Type Builder Error
Error: `App` must be used within `GuidedTour`
    at https://strapi.demia.org/admin/strapi-HBU9X4md.js:2448:6808
    at Kle (https://strapi.demia.org/admin/strapi-HBU9X4md.js:2293:4907)
    at i (https://strapi.demia.org/admin/strapi-HBU9X4md.js:2448:6775)
    at iT (https://strapi.demia.org/admin/index-BOhrbpg6-DvpaPyAk.js:179:23128)
    at f$ (https://strapi.demia.org/admin/strapi-HBU9X4md.js:40:17031)
    at QX (https://strapi.demia.org/admin/strapi-HBU9X4md.js:42:44091)
    at WX (https://strapi.demia.org/admin/strapi-HBU9X4md.js:42:39809)
    at ITe (https://strapi.demia.org/admin/strapi-HBU9X4md.js:42:39735)
    at HS (https://strapi.demia.org/admin/strapi-HBU9X4md.js:42:39585)
    at LO (https://strapi.demia.org/admin/strapi-HBU9X4md.js:42:35947)

Has anyone experienced this to help kindly? All other pages are showing correctly without error.

same problem here, I created an issue here: https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/21982

I found a temporary solution, maybe it will work for you also: https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/21151#issuecomment-2411667883
